# Vlookup in a Loop Process to Change Save Filename VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

All - I am looking to write a loop where I can change the filename and folder location depending on the value that it runs in the loop. For example, if I am running the macro from cells G2:G7, when the process moves from G2 to G3, I want the filename and folder location to change according to some reference table (look image for details). Effectively, I want the filename and foldername to be lookups to the Fund Types.

```
Public Sub Get_File()

    Dim sFiletype As String
    Dim sFilename As String     'Save the file as this name, if "" then default
    Dim sFolder As String       'Save to this folder, if "" then default
    Dim bReplace As Boolean     'To replace the existing file or not
    Dim sURL As String          'The URL to the location to extract information
    Dim cell, Rng As Range
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    'Initialize variables

    Set Rng = Range("I2:I10")
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro_Button")

    For Each cell In Rng
        If cell <> "" Then
        sFiletype = cell.Value
        sFilename = sFiletype & "_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")

        sFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sFiletype, sheet.Range("G2:J10"), 4, False)
        bReplace = True
        sURL = "www.preqin.com"

        'Download using the desired approach, XMLHTTP / IE
        Call Download_Use_IE(sURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)

        Else
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for your input!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6GSs.png

Comment: Can you narrow down this code to exact area you have trouble with? SO encourages a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but also recommends pinpointing relevant parts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait - above is what I am working with but this doesn't seem to be working. I'm currently stuck at the vlookup line and keep getting a runtime error '1004' unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Answer (score 0):

Therein lies the limitation of `VLookUp` where matches must align to the leftmost column and only searches to the right. As advised in the [popular web search](https://www.google.com/#q=vlookup+vs+index+match), consider an `Index/Match` replacement which compares column to column and returns value on matched row (in any direction):

```
sFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sheet.Range("G2:J10"), _
              Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sFiletype, sheet.Range("I2:I10"), 0), 4)
```

If needing to use `VLookUp()`, you would need to decrease your lookup range:

```
sFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sFiletype, sheet.Range("I2:J10"), 2, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `vlookup`, I suggest placing the exact folders into the code given that you only have 8 choices. This makes it readily obvious for debugging. You can do this via a `case` statement. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) for more information.

```
Select Case sFilename

Case abc
    sFolder = "C:\One\"
Case def
    sFolder = "C:\Two\"
Case ghi
    sFolder = "C:\Three\"
'so forth for 8 cases...

End Select
```